# Block Network traffic and take down the Network in docker container

Tags: docker, iptables, docker-container, docker-network

I have created one docker container and I want to perform some network commands over there but i don't know how to do that because i'm new with docker network commands.

1. How to **take down the network** on created container?
2. How to **block network traffic** on created container?

Comment: The following command should be a good start: `docker help network`. For blocking, you will probably have to play with iptables (or whatever replaces it under Mac/Windows).

Comment: @Zeitounator Okay. For `iptables`, do i have to install over there or it will be already exist? On which location it will be exist?

Comment: [nefilter](https://netfilter.org/) used by iptables is part of the kernel. It should already be installed on your host. A simple test: `sudo iptables -L`. Note: iptables is powerfull... thus dangerous. You can easilly lock yourself out a remote machine (typically happens when you are learning).

Comment: I'll add here that, if you're manually using iptables already, you can set up your own virtual interfaces, and this will probably be clearer and easier than trying to cooperate with what Docker sets up.  Docker gives you almost nothing here.  Conversely, if you use a VM, with its own kernel and simulated network stack, you've very isolated from the host and have a couple of ways to easily recover when you do lock yourself out of network access.